# th:if not working with thymeleaf select and options in drop down list

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have spring boot application with thymeleaf. On the view page I want to display a drop down list with options that satisfy a condition otherwise those options should not be there in the drop down list for selection.

The code I came up with is as follows:

```
<select th:field="*{cmClass}" name="classOverridden" id="classOverriddenId" >
    <option value=""  default>[[#{pleaseSelect}]]</option>
    <option value=""  th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated !='1'}" >23</option>
    <option class="text-center" th:value="1"  th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated != '1'}" th:selected="${'1'==answeredQuestionnaire.cmClass}">1</option>
    <option class="text-center" th:value="2"  th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated != '2'}" th:selected="${'2'==answeredQuestionnaire.cmClass}">2</option>
    <option class="text-center" th:value="3" th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated != '3'}"  th:selected="${'3'==answeredQuestionnaire.cmClass}">3</option>
</select>
```

Now for example if the answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated ==1 the first option 23 should not be displayed.
But I see all the options even the condition `th:if="${answeredQuestionnaire.cmClassCalculated !='1'}"` is evaluated to true.
Why th:if is not working here?

Comment: Best guess without seeing the class for answeredQuestionnaire would be that your comparing string against integers.